# bootstrap .row inside a .row-fluid container

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I want to have the ability to place a fixed span div ( span1..span12) inside a **.row-fluid** container.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span5 red">

    <div class="row">
         <div class="span3 gray">
             I need this to span exactly 300px, not 31% of its parent
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="span5 blue">
</div>
```

here is the working jsbin ( sadly you need to enlarge the output pane )--> http://jsbin.com/uwecuv/1/edit

The idea is that the css selector (.row-fluid span3) would take precedence in this case.

Do you guys have any ideas how I can make the 'div.span3.gray' span 300px?

The reason is that in the real scenarion it will be an absolutely positioned div, and I don't want it to inherit the parent's size ( which btw will be just a div with an input box ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap grid system is designed so that `span3` means that element has width=3/12 of the container width (`row` or `row-fluid`). So if you need div with fixed width=300px(not 3/12 of container width) you need to use your own css class with width=300px. Or you can use fixed layout without responsive css.